# Can I set an Icon as titled into a Gtk.StackSwitcher?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

I'd like to set an icon as titled into a Gtk.StackSwitcher with pyGTK.

Is it possible? I didn't see in the [documentation](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#stack-and-stackswitcher).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean Gtk.StackSwitcher ? Gtk.Stack is the empty container in which Gtk.StackSwitcher becomes the "header"

```
   from gi.repository import Gtk

   win  = Gtk.Window () 
   grid = Gtk.Grid ()
   win.add (grid)

   stack = Gtk.Stack ()
   childstack = Gtk.Entry ()
   stack.add_titled (childstack, "_Namestack", "LabelInTheSwitcher")
   grid.attach (stack, 0, 1, 1, 1)

   switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher ()
   switcher.set_stack (stack)
   grid.attach (switcher, 0, 0, 1, 1)

   """ Use icon instead for your switcher """
   stack.child_set_property (childstack, "icon-name", "help-about")


   win.show_all ()
   win.connect ("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

   Gtk.main ()
```

Comment: Awesome response! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works great, but the icon is a little lower (1px in its height, see a screenshot here: http://goo.gl/7Sl1OA ). Could I set the same height as the StackSwitcher? I didn't find a solution :( Thanks in advance luciomrx!

Comment: That is something I couldn't resolved. It is just the way Gtk.Widget allocate their height for each of the widget.

Comment: it seems that show icon only, could the switcher show an icon with a label?